# Character set conversion issue when opening a Sybase-ASE connection from Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, pycharm, sap-ase

I'm at a loss, I'm trying to connect to a Sybase-ASE database from a Python class.

First some version numbers:

- Python - 2.7 (Anaconda 2.1.0 64-bit build)
- Python Sybase library - python-sybase 0.40pre2 (Included in Anaconda)
- Sybase - ASE 12.5.4
- Linux - Red Hat 4.4.7-1
- Shell - Bash 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) (LANG=en_GB.UTF-8)
- Pycharm - Community Edition 4.0.4

The code fails from the command line (irrespective of a character encoding being set or not) and fails within Pycharm too.

I'm executing this line of code:

```
db = Sybase.connect(server, username, password, database)
```

All the credentials are legitimate and work elsewhere, but the error message I get is this:

```
Sybase.DatabaseError: Msg 2401, Level 11, State 2
Character set conversion is not available between client character set 'utf8' and server character set 'iso_1'.
Msg 2411, Level 10, State 1
No conversions will be done.
```

My Google-fu suggests that this is just a warning and can be ignored, however I still need the result of the call to open a cursor to access the DB.

I have no control over the database server config.  Is there something I can set locally in the Python or python-sybase library prior to initial connection to alleviate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems changing then env variable LANG to be:

```
LANG=en_GB
```

Without the UTF-8 suffix fixes the problem.

Comment: this did not work for me. Do you have any other solutions?